# Jqgrid Date Column In 24 Hour Format

Tags: javascript, jqgrid

I am using jqgrid to show grid. I have date column which I want to show the date and time in 24 hour format. But the time is not in 24 hour format. How to show it in 24 hour format ?

```
{
 name: 'CDate', index: 'CDate', sortable: true, align: 'left', formatter: "date", formatoptions: { srcformat: 'Y-m-d H:i:s', newformat: 'd.m.Y h:i A' },
 editable: true, edittype: 'text', resizable: true, hidden: false, viewable: true
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `H` rather than `h`.

> h:    12-hour format of an hour with leading zeros
>
> H:    24-hour format of an hour with leading zeros

Answer (score 0):

If you want to fotmat hours, use this: formatter: "date",  formatoptions: { srcformat: 'H:i:s', newformat: 'h:i:s' }
Hope it helps, regards.